# rdesktop shell escaping issue

Tags: powershell, escaping, remote-desktop

I'm trying to send this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity |Where{$_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_10DE") -or $_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_1002")}
```

over rdesktop like:

```
rdesktop -a8 209.** -u ** -p ** -s "cmd.exe /K powershell.exe Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity |Where{\$_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_10DE") -or $_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_1002")}"
```

But windows' shell says:

```
'Where{$_.DeviceID.StartsWith' is not recognized as an internal or externa....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

why not using powershell wmi remoting?

```
$cred = get-credential
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity -computerName MyRemoteComputerName - credential $cred |Where{$_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_10DE") -or $_.DeviceID.StartsWith("PCI\VEN_1002")}
```

`-credential` are only needed if the actual user running powershell isn't administrator of remote machine.

Comment: because I'm at a linux machine

Answer (score 1):

Hi I needed to do some thing like this once so i wrote some code that can send any ps code to a remote computes and display the results in the ps window on your pc.

Just remember to enable powershell remoting on both pc's.

```
function remote-pscode ($ServerName,$UserName,$password,$PSCode)
{


$global:RemoteCode = $args[0]

Write-Host $RemoteCode
$conprops = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$buffsize = $conprops.BufferSize
$buffsize.Height = 800
$conprops.BufferSize= $buffsize

# Set the user name you would like to use for the connection
$global:RemoteUserName = $UserName
$global:RemoteServerName = $ServerName


# Set the password you would like to use for the connection
# Check to see if you have a file on you drive c:\cred.txt with a password to use in it,if you don't it will create one
# for you and ask you for the password you would like to use 


$global:RemotePassword = convertto-securestring $password -AsPlainText -Force
$global:credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $RemoteUserName,$RemotePassword



#Create a connection to the remote computer , put a list of IPAddresses or Computer Names.
$global:session = new-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteServerName -Credential $credentials


$ScriptBlock = $executioncontext.invokecommand.NewScriptBlock($RemoteCode)

invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock


#Close the sessions that where created     
$global:closesession = Get-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -Session $closesession

}

remote-pscode -ServerName "NameOfRemotePC" -UserName "UserName" -password "password"  -PSCode "any powershell code you want to send to the remote pc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things here: put your PS commands in a [script block](http://www.bjd145.org/2008/02/one-of-interesting-features-that-is-i.html) (or a script). Also, why don't you simply use [wmic.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) ?

Comment: From PowerShell I find `gwmi` much easier to use than `wmic`, especially if you want to extract data and do something with it.